# Problem with Flask API REST and Marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, marshmallow

I'm doing an API with the 'Flask' micro-framework. Basically what I need to do in this case is to be able to insert data from a service with their respective images (gallery). Service and gallery are separate models, so they are related, that is, a service can have many images.

**I have a Models / service.py:**

```
class Service(db.Model):
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    service     = db.Column(db.String(80))
    gallery = db.relationship("Gallery")


    def __init__(self, service, gallery):

        self.service        = service
        self.gallery        = gallery


class Gallery(db.Model):
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_service  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('service.id'))
    image_path  = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self, id_service, image_path):

        self.id_service     = id_service
        self.image_path     = image_path


##### SCHEMAS #####

class GallerySchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        model: Gallery
        fields = ("image_path")
        ordered = True


class ServiceSchema(ma.Schema):

    class Meta:
        model: Service
    id = fields.Integer()
    service = fields.String(required=True)
    gallery = fields.Nested(GallerySchema, many=True)
```

**And I also have Resources / service.py:**

```
    def get(self):
        services = Service.query.all()
        services = services_schema.dump(services)
        return {'status': 'success', 'data': services}, 200

    def post(self):
        json_data = request.get_json()
        if not json_data:
               return {'status': 'error', 'message': 'No input data provided'}, 400

        # Validate and deserialize input
        try:
            data = service_schema.load(json_data)
        except ValidationError as err:
            return {'status': 'error', 'errors': err.messages}, 422



        service = Service(
            service     = data['service'],          
            gallery  = data['gallery']
            )

        db.session.add(service)
        db.session.commit()

        result = service_schema.dump(service)

        return { 'status': 'success', 'data': result }, 201
```

**The POST request is basically:**

```
{           

    "service": "Servicio 1",
    "gallery": [
        {
                   "image_path": "test.png"
        },
         {
                   "image_path": "test.png"
        }
      ]
}
```

**The response when it comes to the POST method shows the following error:**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

**However, the answer when it comes to the GET method is perfect:**

```
     "service": "Servicio de grifo",
     "gallery": [
             {"image_path": "test.png"},
       ]
   }
```

I really don't know the proper way to create a record with related models in a single nested JSON.

I have resorted to many examples, documentation and Internet searches and it has been difficult for me to find the solution to my case. If more to add, I thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add the full traceback, not just the exception.

Comment: You could consider using webargs to parse your inputs with marshmallow.